# Existence of finite fibered atlases

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

It is known - although I personally don't know the proof - that if $X$ is a finite dimensional smooth real manifold of dimension $n$, then there is a smooth finite atlas of $X$ with $n+1$ charts, although they might be disconnected (actually, I know this is true for topological manifolds; is this still true for smooth structures?).

---

Now let $\pi:Y\rightarrow X$ be a smooth fibered manifold (i.e. $\pi$ is a surjective submersion) with $\dim X=n$ and $\dim Y=n+m$. Then $Y$ has a smooth atlas consisting of fibered charts, i.e. charts of the form $(U,x^1,\dots,x^n,y^1,\dots,y^m)$, where the $x^i$ ($i=1,\dots,n$) are constant when restricted to each fibre.

My question is, does $Y$ also have a finite atlas consisting of *fibered* charts?

Comment: The "known" fact was not known by me. Can you give a reference?

Comment: @DanAsimov I have read this in Kolár/Michor/Slovák: Natural Operations in Differential Geometry. That book itself refers to Greub/Halperin/Vanstone: Connections, Curvature and Cohomology vol I. I have just checked that book and it appears I might able to prove my question in the positive, because even though the fundamental aspects of the proof are beyond me, the difficult stuff is neatly tucked into a nice theorem (Theorem I in the latter book in Chapter I) that can be applied to multiple situations. But now it is late where I am, so I won't work on this today. Answers are still welcome.

Comment: This also means that this result is certainly true for smooth manifolds too.